# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path

Tags: java, rxtx

I am trying to use the 64 bit rxtx serial communication library (downloaded from cloudhopper) with 64bit windows 7 and eclipse.  I get the message:
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path`.  The dlls are in the `/jre/lib` dir as well as the `Windows/System32`.  The `RXTXcomm.jar` is in the build path for eclipse as well as in the `jre/lib/ext` dir.  I ran process monitor in the background and and see that `RXTXcomm.jar`, `rxtxSerial.dll`, and `rxtxParallel.dll` are all found and have been opened,  So I am unclear as to why this problem is occurring.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 21):

Go to Project -> properties -> Java build path ->Find your .jar. 
Click on + to open the JAR's properties.
Select Native library location and edit it to point to RXTX's shared library (.DLL, .so, .dylib).

Comment: It helped, the easiest and fastest way. ;)

Answer (score 10):

You can install `librxtx-java` package from repo for Ubuntu.

Comment: Weird thing is, it is installed on my system, yet I'm getting this message. Weird.

Comment: @Doc it works if you specify location, java **-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni** -jar YourApp.jar

Answer (score 7):

You can also add a virtual machine argument:

```
-Djava.library.path=c:\path\to\dll\
```

or

```
-Djava.library.path=/path/to/lib/
```

That worked for me. Also refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751304/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-rxtxserial-in-java-library-path-thrown-while).

Answer (score 4):

*Windows user* : my problem was actually that I was placing the *rxtxSerial.dll* and the *rxtxParallel.dll* files in the wrong directory.

In my case, they were in **[...]/jdk1.7.0_09/bin/** instead of **[...]/jre7/bin/**, although paths may differ for different versions of Java.

After all it's logic, if we want our JAR to run outside our IDE, we must have the dlls in our java running environment, not in our development environment :)

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this problem by adding rxtxSerial.dll[jre 1.8.0_45/bin] and RxTxcomm.jar[jre 1.8.0_45/lib/ext]

Comment: set the build path as jre 1.8.0_45/lib/ext/RxTxComm.jar

Answer (score 2):

Hy, I had the same problem when integrating the RXTXcomm into Netbeans under Ubuntu 11.10.
I am guessing that you are not copying the files in the right place, at least that was my problem.

Under Ubuntu java is installed under usr/lib/jvm. BUT here I had a lot of forders (ex *java-7-openjdk-i386*, *java-7-common*, *java-6-openjdk* ...). In Netbeans I check what is the path of the JDK included into the project, it was *java-7-openjdk-i386* . so I took the rxtxSerial.so (under windows it is rxtxSerial.dll) and copied it to *java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin* and it worked like a charm .

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have read that as well and I have placed the dll files and the jar in the right place and the process monitor indicates that the jvm sees them.  That is why I am confused.

Comment: This helped me set up Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem even after installing the RXTXcomm.jar in the Java\jdk\lib directory. Based on the instructions at http://www.jcontrol.org/download/readme_rxtx_en.html
I located the rxtxSerial.dll and the rxtxParallel.dll files.  Placing them in the bin directory did not help, but placing them in the lib directory along with the RXTXcomm.jar solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So I installed JDK 32-bit and added those `RxTx` files(x86) to **Program files(x86)/java/...** folder instead of **Program files/java...** folder. Also I added those *RxTx* .dll files(x86) to **/System32** folder. After that the problem was resolved in my application.

Answer (score 1):

**FIXED:**

when using IDE such Netbeans it has it's own directory for the JRE, were you probably installed your RXTX drivers, but when running the JAR file outside your IDE this error occurs...
**Solution** is install the RXTX drivers also inside the JAVA JRE directory which use to run all your JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

> Under Netbeans 5.5 on Windows, I needed to right-click Libraries under
>   Projects on the left hand side of the screen, and select "Add
>   JAR/Folder", picking the RXTXcomm.jar file. Only then did my

```
enter code here
```

> become a valid command.
>   Also, I got a run-time error where it failed to load the
>   rxtxSerial.DLL library because it couldn't find it. I needed to
>   right-click the project name, select properties, select Run under
>   categories, and add a VM Options: entry of

-Djava.library.path="C:\where-ever-you-stuck-rxtxSerial.DLL-file;%PATH%

> Example:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2\Windows\i368-mingw32\;%PATH%"
```

> While I'm sure there is more than one way of adding the directory to
>   your path, this worked for me. Note I did the default NetBeans 5.5/JDK
>   1.6.0 isntall accepting all the default options(ie clicking next until I got to finish), so I haven't modified my java paths or anything.
>   Alternatively you can copy the *.dll into C:\Windows\System32\, Java
>   will find it there automatically.

Note that you cannot use the 32bit DLL when running a 64bit JRE:
You will get an error similar to:

```
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

> To solve this simply install the 32bit JDK and add a new Platform in
>   Netbeans under Tools->Java Platforms->Add Platform and change the
>   project settings to use the newly created platform. make sure you type

`"import gnu.io.*"`

from http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Using_RXTX_In_NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, on windows 10 and eclipse, the probelm was i had java for 32 and 64 bits, so i installed RXTX library for 64 bits but eclipse was using the 32 bits java enviroment, so what i did was download RXTX for 32 bits copy the necessary files to C:ProgramFilesx86/JAVA_HOME as in the instructions for RXTX and the problem was solved. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I was trying to run built jar file from dist folder and it was not working even it was working from NetBeans IDE. I copied rxtxSerial.dll file in dist folder where my main jar file was and it started working fine.

I was having this error before:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while
loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in
java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:123)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.smslib.helper.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java
:72)
        at org.smslib.modem.SerialModemDriver.connectPort(SerialModemDriver.java
:69)
        at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:114)
        at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
        at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```