# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver

Tags: java, fedora, rxtx

Fedora using right now (package is installed `Package rxtx-2.2-0.5.20100211.fc15.i686 already installed and latest version`
).

I have used/tried:

```
# locate librxtxSerial
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Linux/ia64-unkown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/librxtxSerial.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Mac_OS_X/librxtxSerial.jnilib
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc32-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so
/home/sun/Downloads/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2/Solaris/sparc-solaris/sparc64-sun-solaris2.8/librxtxSerial.so
/usr/lib/rxtx/librxtxSerial-2.2pre1.so
/usr/lib/rxtx/librxtxSerial.so
```

Then used:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/rxtx/librxtxSerial.so -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

But still i get always this following:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at main.Tty.sendCommand1(Tty.java:212)
    at main.Tty.main(Tty.java:236)
```

How to resolve this ?

**Follow up:**

WRONG:

`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/rxtx -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni`

CORRECT

`-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/rxtx`

Comment: seems you have some libraries are missing.

Comment: Please post the java code you are using to load the lib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you have multiple `-Djava.library.path` parameters and the second one is overwriting the value of the first. The value should also be the path to the folder containing the library, not including the library name.

On linux system you should be able to combine both path parameters using a colon as separator:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/rxtx:/usr/lib/jni
```

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem with v4l4j library installed from repositories. In ununtu netbeans project failed to start from IDE, but worked fine as jar.

Solved by putting *.so files to `/usr/lib` not `/usr/lib/jni` folder.

Comment: Best of best answer! This method works for pidora os also :thumbsup

Comment: This worked for me in Raspbian as well! I first installed RXTX drivers using `sudo apt-get install librxtx-java` and then copied all the files /usr/lib and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Project -> properties -> Java build path ->Find your .jar. 
Click on + to open the JAR's properties.
Select Native library location and edit it to point to RXTX's shared library (.DLL, .so, .dylib).

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on linux.
The key for us to fix it was

1. Use colon ":" to separate java.library.path elements
2. Use forward slash for directory separators

In our case we used a relative path like this

```
-Djava.library.path=jar/linux64:jars
```

The path is relative to the startup path. E.g. when running from netbeans the startup directory is the project directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
Copy RXTXcomm.jar ---> <JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\ext
```

`Copy rxtxSerial.dll ---> <JAVA_HOME>\jre\bin`

`Copy rxtxParallel.dll ---> <JAVA_HOME>\jre\bin`