# no rxtxSerial in java.library.path

Tags: java, spring-boot, serial-port

i am trying to establish communication between spring boot and serial so i can read data and send it through serial i found this code and tried to run it

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {                  "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM4", // Windows
    };
    private BufferedReader input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }


    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=null;
                if (input.ready()) {
                    inputLine = input.readLine();
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000    seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them    (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException    ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

but I got this error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52120:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\IdeaProjects\databasedemo\target\classes;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.11.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.11.2\log4j-api-2.11.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.26\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.4\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.24\snakeyaml-1.24.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring5\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.0.11.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.5.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-java8time\3.0.4.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-web-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-json-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.8\jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.8\jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.8\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.8\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.19\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.19.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.1\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.16.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.16.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.0.M2\spring-web-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.0.M2\spring-webmvc-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.0.M2\spring-expression-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\microsoft\sqlserver\mssql-jdbc\6.4.0.jre8\mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.2\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.9.12\byte-buddy-1.9.12.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.0.M2\spring-core-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.0.M2\spring-jcl-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.4\aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\3.3.1\HikariCP-3.3.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.2.0.M2\spring-jdbc-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.1\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.2\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.2\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.4.2.Final\hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.24.0-GA\javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.5.Final\jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.0\classmate-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\dom4j\dom4j\2.1.1\dom4j-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.0.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.2\txw2-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.8\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\jvnet\staxex\stax-ex\1.8.1\stax-ex-1.8.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\fastinfoset\FastInfoset\1.2.16\FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.2.0.M4\spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.M4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.2.0.M4\spring-data-commons-2.2.0.M4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.2.0.M2\spring-orm-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.2.0.M2\spring-tx-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.2.0.M2\spring-aspects-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.7\velocity-1.7.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-starter-security-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.0.M2\spring-aop-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-web-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-config-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.2.0.M2\spring-security-core-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.0.M2\spring-beans-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.0.M2\spring-context-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\fazecast\jSerialComm\2.5.1\jSerialComm-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.6.2\javax.mail-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.2.0.M3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.M3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.0.4.RELEASE\spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\2.0.1.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\5.2.0.M2\spring-context-support-5.2.0.M2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\rxtx\rxtx\2.1.7\rxtx-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\bidib\com\neuronrobotics\nrjavaserial\3.12.0\nrjavaserial-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.26\slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-websocket\4.1.6.RELEASE\spring-websocket-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-adapter-sample\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-adapter-sample-1.0.0.BUILD-20170627.122039-9.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.091103-352.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-context\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-context-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.090751-398.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\cloud\spring-cloud-function-core\1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT\spring-cloud-function-core-1.0.0.BUILD-20180618.090651-400.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\io\projectreactor\reactor-core\3.3.0.M1\reactor-core-3.3.0.M1.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.2\reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar;C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-messaging\5.2.0.M2\spring-messaging-5.2.0.M2.jar com.example.databasedemo.SerialTest
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\php\php_runningversion, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\Program Files\dotnet\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\nodejs\, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, C:\Program Files\Git\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\, C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.3.5\bin, ., C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AppData\Roaming\npm, ., .] thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin, C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\binaries\php\php_runningversion, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\Program Files\dotnet\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\nodejs\, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, C:\Program Files\Git\bin, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\, C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2018.3.5\bin, ., C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\AppData\Roaming\npm, ., .]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
    at gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:83)
    at com.example.databasedemo.SerialTest.initialize(SerialTest.java:27)
    at com.example.databasedemo.SerialTest.main(SerialTest.java:86)
```

i tried to add it manually but nothing changed i don't know what to do please help how can i add this library in my spring boot app i even tried to add it in the pom file (i am using maven)
**UPDATE:**
based on the link given to me in the commants i got red of that error but got new one here it is

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180003990, pid=12940, tid=19288
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0+28) (build 11+28)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11+28, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x3990]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\IdeaProjects\databasedemo\hs_err_pid12940.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197639/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-rxtxserial-in-java-library-path)

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8197639/11476836) helps

Comment: thank you but i got an other error you can see it in update

Comment: Now it looks like an architecture mismatch, have you installed the 64 bit or 32 bit arch from [here](http://jlog.org/rxtx-win.html)? I imagine you're on Windows 10 64 bit... I think this is quite an old library. This is the [most recent](https://github.com/github-byl/Java-RxTx-in-Windows-10-USB-COM-ports) reference I can find, maybe it helps.... Otherwise, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317576/stable-alternative-to-rxtx) for an alternative.

Comment: as you can see on their [github](https://github.com/rxtx/rxtx) rxtx was last updated 6 years ago. I would suggest switching to [jrxtx](https://github.com/openmuc/jrxtx) which improves on the old rxtx.

Comment: To add jrxtx to your maven just add the dependency to your pom file. [Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openmuc/jrxtx/1.0.1)